# How to cancel selection in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, selection

On my page, I have a `contenteditable` `div` element. When a specific key is pressed, a function executes:

```
function bla(element) {
  if (getSelectionHtml() != "") {
    replaceSelectedText("text");
  }
}
```

`getSelectionHtml()` checks if something is selected by the user. `replaceSelectedText(text)` replaces the selected text with a given string. Both functions are working properly.
After the selected text has been replaced, I want to 'cancel' the user's selection, as the selection is now equal to the 'new' string, so just deleting the text is not an option.

I tried this:

```
element.style.userSelect = "none";
element.style.userSelect = "text;
```

But it didn't work because `userSelect: none` doesn't seem to change anything in a div element with `contenteditable`. Also, this solution looks pretty ugly for such a simple problem.

So, how can I cancel the user's selection?

Comment: try element.selection.empty();

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal I tried: the function throws error _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'empty' of undefined_ :(

Comment: How about document.selection.empty();

Comment: element.selection is supportable in IE I think. Can you tell which browser you used?

Comment: @AkanshGulati I'm using Chrome

Comment: document.selection is defined for IE < 9, while window.getSelection is compatible with most browsers now. @SanchitPatiyal

Comment: I see anyway `window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()` will do the trick @AkanshGulati

Comment: Yes, I think you mean `window.getSelection().empty()`? I tested it and that does the job as well. But anyways, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, they both are alias of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to remove selection completely. You can do so once you have replaced the string with

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
```

So basically, once you select the range of content, you can get the range with `window.getSelection()` method which returns set of details about selected content. It has many functions to alter the range and remove the range completely. To know more, you can read in brief of all supported methods [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine. I didn't expect it to be this simple! :)